# How to write a find and replace script in Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to write a script that takes a text version of a formula starting with "@" and replaces it with "=" so that the formula actually works. I have tried to use replace and substitute formulas but after running those formulas, the original formulas don't pull.

Here is a link to the spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OTVzynWNsi7NJ6-3gFonrrWhy2lKq_ibe6KG-p5Yibk/edit#gid=725037056

Here is what my current script looks like:

```
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Formulas!A16:M17').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();

  //This is where the find replace formula needs to go
  currentCell.toString().replace("@", "=");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function copyFormulas() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName('Formulas');
  var srg=ssh.getRange('A16:M17');
  var vA=srg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA[1].length;i++) {
    vA[1][i]=vA[1][i].toString().replace('@','=');    
  }
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Script');
  dsh.getRange(1,1,1,srg.getWidth()).setValues([vA[0]]);
  dsh.getRange(2,1,1,srg.getWidth()).setFormulas([vA[1]]);
}
```

Comment: You are my hero!! Thanks for helping me out with that!